# C# Should "as string" work like this?

Tags: c#, string-conversion

as string caused me a problem when dealing with object arrays. The values after execution are shown in the comments. Should it work this way?

```
object[] array = new object[2]; 
array[0] = 0.33;
array[1] = "0.33";
string a = array[0] as string; // a == null !!!??????
string b = array[1] as string; // b == "0.33"
string a2 = array[0] == null ? "" : array[0].ToString(); // a2 == "0.33"
string a3 = Convert.ToString(array[0]); // a3 == "0.33"
```

Comment: `as string` is not `ToString()`.

Comment: +1 @BoltClock However, in his defense, I can see how that *could be* confusing for someone who's learning .NET

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it should.

`as` is a cast operator.
It can only be used to cast an object to a type that it actually is (or a superclass thereof).

`x as Y` returns `null` if `x` isn't a `Y`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll avoid it in the future except when I need to do a cast.

Answer (score 2):

the as-operator returns null when it fails to cast an object to the specified type. in this case it failed to cast 0.33 to type string, so string a is null.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception

So yes, the behaviour you are observing is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator is a casting operation, not a conversion operation, so it will only produce the value is the same type, or a super- or sub-class or the type you are trying to cast to.

(Unlike a regular cast, the `as` operator also does not perform user-defined conversions using the `operator` keyword.)

Answer (score 0):

"as string" is not a synonym for "ToString()".  You are using the "as" operator, and happened to pass it string as a type.

[Definition of the as operator:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Remarks

The as operator is like a cast except that it yields null on conversion failure instead of raising an exception. More formally, an expression of the form:

expression as type
is equivalent to:

expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null

Answer (score 0):

The 'as' operator is basically like casting into a System.Type however the only difference is that it returns a null value if the cast fails instead of throwing an exception.

Check out this link for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`array[0]` is a `double` and cannot be casted to `string`, hence `null`.
Call `ToString()`, most types override it to return something meaningful.